# create one table from with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE New_table AS (SELECT * FROM Old_table)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE New_table AS SELECT * FROM Old_table
```

I have run the above two command in SQL server.
but for the two command showing the below error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

What should be the correct code?

Comment: would be handy to know the database that you are using

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: SELECT *  INTO New_table FROM Old_table

Answer (score 3):

If the table doesn't exist yet, you can use

```
SELECT *
INTO New_Table
FROM Existing_table
```

If that new table already exists, then you must use

```
INSERT INTO New_Table(list of columns)
    SELECT (list of columns)
    FROM Existing_table
```

Comment: Thanks. its working. but if the Existing table is in different database on the same server what should I do?

Comment: Then you need to use the three-part name: `INSERT INTO database.dbo.New_Table(list of columns) ....`

Comment: SELECT *
INTO cib_ISD.New_table (dept,deptname)
FROM esblmis.existing_table

I am writing like this way. where CIB_ISD is destination database and ESBLMIS is source database. but showing some error....

Comment: SELECT *
INTO cib_ISD.New_table (dept,deptname)
FROM esblmis.existing_table

I am writing like this way. where CIB_ISD is destination database and ESBLMIS is source database. but showing some error....

Comment: @Md.AbdulMasudRana: What error you received ? You can't define the column names when using `SELECT * INTO`. If the table is already exist you need to use `INSERT INTO` only. Or use `SELECT dept,deptname INTO cib_ISD.New_table FROM esblmis.existing_table`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'dept'.

Comment: @Md.AbdulMasudRana `SELECT dept,deptname INTO cib_ISD.New_table FROM esblmis.existing_table` will work in your case

Comment: SELECT dept,deptname INTO cib_ISD.inters FROM ESBLMIS.dept         I have run this but showing the below error.         Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'ESBLMIS.dept'.

Comment: @Md.AbdulMasudRana: `ESBLMIS.dept`, here you missed the `schemaname` like dbo., so hope its `ESBLMIS.dbo.dept`,

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want data ,you can use

--This populates only schema

```
select 
* into newtable from oldtable where 1=2

select top 0 * into newtable from oldtable
```

Comment: I want to copy data too.

Comment: In that case,you can use Marc answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table 
FROM old_table;
```

Comment: Instead of creating new answer, you can edit and update in your exist answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360024/create-one-table-from-with-another-table/37360047#comment62234496_37360047) by the OP, he tried to insert **only few columns** from one database's table to another database's table.

The below query worked in his case:

```
SELECT dept, deptname INTO cib_ISD.dbo.inters 
FROM ESBLMIS.dbo.dept
```